# php missing attributes while parsing XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml coming from a API.

```
    <response>
<ads numAds="2">
<ad ranking="1">
<title>Artist News on Facebook®</title>
<description>
What&#39;s the most current music news? Sign up For Free to Find out!
</description>
<pixel_url>
http://cc.xdirectx.com/pixellink.php?qry=e8b6b726c
</pixel_url>
<url visibleurl="Facebook.com">
http://cc.xdirectx.com/clicklink.php?qry=067a9027
</url>
</ad>
<ad ranking="2">
<title>Artist News on Facebook®</title>
<description>
What&#39;s the most current music news? Sign up For Free to Find out!
</description>
<pixel_url>
http://cc.xdirectx.com/pixellink.php?qry=e8b6b726c
</pixel_url>
<url visibleurl="Facebook.com">
http://cc.xdirectx.com/clicklink.php?qry=067a9027
</url>
</ad>
</ads></response>
```

When I try to parse using **simplexml_load_string** or **SimpleXMLElement** I am getting this result.

[ads] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [numAds] => 6
                )

```
        [ad] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [ranking] => 1
                            )

                        [title] => Artist News on Facebook®
                        [description] => What's the most current music news? Sign up For Free to Find out!
                        [pixel_url] => http://cc.xdirectx.com/pixellink.php?qry=e8b6b726c
                        [url] => http://cc.xdirectx.com/clicklink.php?qry=067a9027
                    )
               )
```

The important thing missing is url visibleurl attribute which I need.
I tried looking online and wasted complete day in fixing this, but no answer.
Can someone rectify the mistake I am doing?

PHP CODE:

```
$result = getCurlJson($urlParse);
$output = simplexml_load_string($result) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';

function getCurlJson($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing `print_r($output);` to `print_r($output->ad->url);` in your code, and see what the output is?

Comment: @zinga that shows only the main data text.. like http://cc.xdirectx.com/clicklink.php?qry=067a9027

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  It returns the full object with attributes for me, tested on PHP 5.4 and 5.6.  Full code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/6uVyE5Xt

Comment: Can you check this: http://pastebin.com/J3yGb3jQ This is how i am getting the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading of the XML works fine, but `print_r` is not able to print everything from an XML `object`. See this repository for a solution if you want to dump the XML code: [simplexml_debug](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug)

You can access the attribute you want with

```
echo $output->ads->ad[0]->url->attributes();
```

Which works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you.. Silly me I never tried this :(. I was just looking why printr / vardump is not showing result.